# Ruby on rails - shrink length of an entry on validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to limit the size of the data and if it exceeds i want it to be to shrinked to the limit. is there any easy way to do this??

my validation code:

```
validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 80 }
```

for example the data is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore

i want it to be shrinked to:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), you should do this in `before_validation`. You can truncate the string with [String#truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) provided by ActiveSupport.

Example:

```
before_validation do
  self.title = title.truncate(80, :omission => '...')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just put this in a `before_create` function since you are not really *validating* anything - you just want the data changed under certain conditions. Also, you might want to consider keeping the long title and making a function like `short_title` that returns a shrunk version - this gives you the same functionality and you might end up needing the longer title.

```
before_create :shrink_title

...

def shrink_title
  self.title = title[0...77] + '...' if title.length > 80
end
```

or

```
def short_title
  (title.length > 80) ? title[0...77] + '...' : title
end
```